# Авторизация с OAuth2-proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, oauth

хочу разобраться как развернуть веб сервис nginx c аутификацией через OAuht2-proxy на виндовом сервере. Имеются докер образы nginx и OAuht2-proxy но как правильно из запустить и настроить я не могу найти... Прочитал кучу материала, но так и не понял как это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто с эти сталкивался или работал.

Comment: если вы спрашиваете об этом прокси https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/ то для его работы не нужен Nginx

Comment: Да, все верно, но если я правильно понимаю, то единственный способ запустить oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy на виндовом сервисе, это использовать контейнеры, но я не могу найти информацию как это сделать с образом предоставленным oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy.

Comment: Есть пребилд для винды https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/releases/download/v7.3.0/oauth2-proxy-v7.3.0.windows-amd64.tar.gz